# Как заменить повторяющиеся группы элементов с помощью replaceAll?

Tags: java, строки

Вопрос относительно метода `replaceAll` в `String`.

Допустим, есть строка, содержащая строковое представление xml, где повторяются элементы:

```
<Users>
 <User>
  <Name>Alex</Name>
  <Company>Gazprom</Company>
 </User>
 <User>
  <Name>Irina</Name>
  <Company>Lukoil</Company>
 </User>
</Users
```

И мне нужно заменить для обоих пользователей в строке компанию на "Rosneft".
Если я применю к строке следующее регулярное выражение:

```
line.replaceAll("<Company>.*</Company>", "<Company>Rosneft</Company>");
```

То получится так:

```
<Users>
 <User>
  <Name>Alex</Name>
  <Company>Rosneft</Company>
 </User>
</Users
```

Взялась строка до первого вхождения "Сompany", вырезалась до последнего закрывающего тэга в пользователе "Irina" и заменилась на новую компанию. Как  этого избежать?

Comment: Вы исправили и все стало как вам надо. Только кавычки проверьте

Comment: Замените `.*` на `.*?`

Comment: @Regent да, отставьте как ответ пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для отключения "жадности" поиска используется квантификатор `?`:

```
line.replaceAll("<Company>.*?</Company>", "<Company>Rosneft</Company>");
```

Описание работы квантификаторов, например, есть [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-greedy-and-lazy) и [здесь](https://habr.com/post/68345/)

Comment: Да и без ? работает

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець а вы пробовали? Причем именно если в `line` нет переводов строк

Comment: да, без перевода строк не работает